# Google Map Memory Issue

Tags: swift, google-maps, memory, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I am working on a project where I need ViewController to show **Google Map** to indicate the location of Property and many other objects like table view and collection view to show JSON Data on the same view controller.

**Problem:** This ViewController taking memory near about 72 MB and when I debug the code to check why it's taking much memory then I have observed Google Map is the reason. If I removed the Google map then its only took 15 MB space, however, I have created other view controller in which I took only UIView and gave it type GMSMapView and when I run the code it was taking near 70 MB memory.

**Is it normal behavior of google map?** As I haven't written any code just assigned the type GMSMapView to UIView and it was taking a huge memory.

I need a solution to decrease this memory problem. Can anybody suggest how we can do that in the case of Google map?

**Please note: I haven't written any code for Google MapView, just assigned the GMSMapView type to UIView and memory jump to near 70 MB and above.**

Comment: Make google map outlet as weak

Comment: @SarabjitSingh Its already weak.

Comment: "just assigned the GMSMapView type to UIView and memory jump to near 70 MB and above" - Can't confirm your experience on that, try to find where you might be instantiating it. I have several views and xibs doing that, no memory impact until they are instantiated. Once 1 is instantiated though, memory impact is around 50MB and 20MB of it never goes away, even if all GMSMapViews are dealloced. These 20MB are "cached/internal" things that Google SDK just keeps in memory for "in case". Reported as a bug to Google iOS Map SDK issue tracker. You can star my issue to raise its priority to Google :).

Answer (score 2):

I used it my app( online taxi app ) and I think it's normal but for making the memory usage lesser you can remove GMSMapView when viewController didDisappear

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        mapView.clear()
        mapView.removeFromSuperview()
        mapView = nil
       }
```

it causes your app uses less memory